# Java: How to call a constructor of class that extends Comparable, with Anytype [ ] as a paramater?

Tags: java, object, constructor

For the life of me I cannot figure out how this syntax would work.

```
public class BinaryHeap<AnyType extends Comparable<? super AnyType>>
{

...

 public BinaryHeap( AnyType [ ] items )
{
        currentSize = items.length;
        array = (AnyType[]) new Comparable[ ( currentSize + 2 ) * 11 / 10 ];

        int i = 1;
        for( AnyType item : items )
            array[ i++ ] = item;
        buildHeap( );
}
} // end class
```

Ive been bashing my head against a wall trying to figure out why,

```
int heapElements[] //assume its populated from above
BinaryHeap<Integer> myBH = new BinaryHeap<Integer>(heapElements[]);
```

The error I get from Eclipse is:

```
The constructor BinaryHeap(Class<heapElements[]>) is undefined
```

Comment: Generics, primitive types, and arrays don't play well. Use a `Collection` type.

Comment: You're setting the type argument as `Integer`, yet you're trying to pass an array object (`int[]`) to the constructor instead of an Integer object. You'd have to change the type argument from `Integer` to `int[]` to accept that constructor argument

Comment: int and Integer are different types.

Comment: Do you *need* AnyType to implement Comparable? If so, you're out of luck, cause arrays and lists don't implement it. Why do you need comparable in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

First, you cannot pass "heapElements[]" as a function argument, it's incorrect syntax.

Second, you cannot instantiate BinaryHeap of primitive type int. Java language doesn't permit substitution of primitive types as generic type parameters. For example,

```
ArrayList<int>
```

is illegal construction.

One of the options is to use Integer instead of int. But that leads to some overhead related to autoboxing.

Another option is to use primitive collections library such as GNU Trove http://trove.starlight-systems.com/

Comment: But you can choose a primitive array as the type argument, which seems to be what he's trying to pass in (not just a primitive value, but an array object full of primitives, which is allowed in generics). If you want, check out my comment and steal the answer if you please